# Mat-table doesn't show data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-table

My mat-table does not show any data after an API call. It does show data when I directly inject the data, even though to me, it seems exactly the same. I can't seem to find why this goes wrong.

prijslijst.component.html

```js
<div id="prijslijst_bier">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceAlcohol" class="mat-table">

    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
  
    <!--  Naam Column -->
     <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let alcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{alcohol.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>  
  
    <!-- Begin prijs Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="startPrice">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> Beginprijs </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let alcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{alcohol.startPrice}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Actuele prijs Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="currentPrice">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> Actuele prijs </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let alcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{alcohol.currentPrice}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Aantal verkocht Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="numberSold">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> # </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let alcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{alcohol.numberSold}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="addOrder(row)"></tr>
</table>  
</div>

<div id="prijslijst_fris">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceNonAlcohol" class="mat-table">
  
      <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
            The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
    
      <!--  Naam Column -->
       <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let nonAlcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{nonAlcohol.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>  
    
      <!-- Begin prijs Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="startPrice">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> Start Price </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let nonAlcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{nonAlcohol.startPrice}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Actuele prijs Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="currentPrice">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> Current Price </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let nonAlcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{nonAlcohol.currentPrice}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Aantal verkocht Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="numberSold">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="mat-header-cell"> # </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let nonAlcohol" class="mat-cell"> {{nonAlcohol.numberSold}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="addOrder(row)"></tr>
  </table>  
  </div>
```

prijslijst.component.ts

```
typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatTableDataSourcePaginator} from '@angular/material/table';
import { DrinksService } from '../drinks/drinks.service';
import { Drink } from '../drinks/drink';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prijslijst',
  templateUrl: './prijslijst.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prijslijst.component.css']
})
export class PrijslijstComponent {
  private alcohols: Drink[] = [];
  private nonAlcohols: Drink[] = [];
  dataSourceAlcohol!: MatTableDataSource<Drink, MatTableDataSourcePaginator>;
  dataSourceNonAlcohol!: MatTableDataSource<Drink, MatTableDataSourcePaginator>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'startPrice', 'currentPrice', 'numberSold'];

  constructor(private drinksService: DrinksService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateDrinks();
    this.dataSourceAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.alcohols);
    this.dataSourceNonAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.nonAlcohols);
  }

  addOrder(drink: Drink) {
    drink.numberInOrder = drink.numberInOrder + 1;
  }

  updateDrinks(): void {
    this.alcohols = this.drinksService.getAlcoholDrinks();
    this.nonAlcohols = this.drinksService.getNonAlcoholDrinks();
  }
}
```

drink.service.ts

```
typescript
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Drink } from './drink';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DrinksService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/drinks';
  drinks: Drink[] = [];

  setupDrinks(): void {
    this.getDrinks().subscribe(drinks => {
      drinks.forEach(drink => this.drinks.push(drink))
    });
  }

  getDrinks(): Observable<Drink[]> {
    console.log('getDrinks')
    return this.http.get<Drink[]>(this.url);
  }

  getAlcoholDrinks(): Drink[] {
    let alcoholDrinks: Drink[] = [];
    this.getDrinks().subscribe(drinks => {
      drinks.forEach(drink => {
        if(drink.alcohol) {
          alcoholDrinks.push(drink);
        }
      });
    });
    return alcoholDrinks;
  }

  getNonAlcoholDrinks(): Drink[] {
    let nonAlcoholDrinks: Drink[] = [];
    this.getDrinks().subscribe(drinks => {
      drinks.forEach(drink => {
        if(drink.alcohol === false) {
          nonAlcoholDrinks.push(drink);
        }
      });
    });

    return nonAlcoholDrinks;
  }

  setSoldOut(drinkName: string) {
    this.drinks.filter((drink) => {
      if(drink.name === drinkName) {
        drink.soldOut = true;
      }
    })
  }

  setDrinks(drinks: Drink[]) {
    this.drinks = drinks;
  }

}
```

I can get it to work when, in `updateDrinks()`, I set the `alcoholDrinks` as follows

```js
updateDrinks(): void {
    this.alcohols = [{ name: "pintje", alcohol: true, startPrice: 1.5, currentPrice: 1.5, numberSold: 0, numberInOrder: 0, soldOut: false},
    { name: "desperados", alcohol: true, startPrice: 1.5, currentPrice: 2.5, numberSold: 0, numberInOrder: 0, soldOut: false}]
  }
```

When looking at the logs, the arrays display differently as well. The working solution says `(2) [{…}, {…}]`, and with the non-working version `[]`. I added a screenshot of this here. Apart from that, it all looks the same...

[image: log screenshot]

The backend (NestJs) function below:

```js
@Get()
    async getDrinks(@Res() res: Response) {
        this.logger.log("GET: getDrinks()")
        res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
        res.send(this.drinksService.getAllDrinks());
    }
```

Returning this json

```json
[
    {
        "name": "karmeliet",
        "alcohol": true,
        "startPrice": 1.8,
        "numberInOrder": 0,
        "currentPrice": 1.8,
        "numberSold": 0,
        "soldOut": false
    },
    {
        "name": "cola",
        "alcohol": false,
        "startPrice": 1.8,
        "numberInOrder": 0,
        "currentPrice": 1.8,
        "numberSold": 0,
        "soldOut": false
    },
    {
        "name": "test",
        "alcohol": true,
        "startPrice": 1.8,
        "numberInOrder": 0,
        "currentPrice": 1.8,
        "numberSold": 0,
        "soldOut": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an asynchronous issue. at the time when you are assigning the `dataSourceAlcohol` and `dataSourceNonAlcohol` properties in `ngOnInit` the values are empty array and after some milliseconds they are getting the values from the API call.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateDrinks();  // <-- you need to wait to get the values from the server and after continue the value assignments
    this.dataSourceAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.alcohols);
    this.dataSourceNonAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.nonAlcohols);
  }
```

So you need to little bit modify your code in different places:

Let's start.

In `drink.service.ts` let's remove `getAlcoholDrinks` and `getNonAlcoholDrinks`  methods and create a new one `getDrinksByGroup` that will return both (**as I understand you are doing the same API call for both.**)

```
  getDrinksByGroup(): Observable<{alcohols: Drink[], notAlcohols: Drink[] }> {
    // import map from RxJS operators
   return this.getDrinks().pipe(map(drinks => {
      const alcoholDrinks: Drink[] = [];
      const notAlcoholDrinks: Drink[] = [];
    
      drinks.forEach(drink => {
        if(drink.alcohol) {
          alcoholDrinks.push(drink);
        } else {
          notAlcoholDrinks.push(drink)
        }
      });

      return { alcohols: alcoholDrinks, notAlcohols: notAlcoholDrinks };
    });

  }
```

in your component let's modify these part of codes(**at first let's remove `updateDrinks` and let's create the `getDrinks` method like bellow and also update the code inside `ngOnInit` **):

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.getDrinks();
  }

  getDrinks() {
    this.drinksService
        .getDrinksByGroup()
        .subscribe(({alcohols, notAlcohols}) => {
           this.alcohols = alcohols;
           this.nonAlcohols = notAlcohols;
           this.dataSourceAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.alcohols);
           this.dataSourceNonAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.nonAlcohols);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This does indeed work, thanks a lot! I should have realised it happened asynchronously, thanks for pointing that out, another lesson learned!